# MFC virtual List Control LVFINDINFO

Tags: search, mfc, listcontrol

I'm going to make a search function in mfc virtual list control

However, even if i change the search method, always output only the 0th row I don't know what the problem is.

i searched 0th column value

```
void CListControlDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    CListCtrl* ListCtrl = ((CListCtrl*)GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1));

    CString aaaa;

    aaaa.Format("%d", 56);

        LVFINDINFO f1;
        f1.flags = LVFI_STRING;
        f1.psz = aaaa;
        f1.vkDirection = VK_DOWN; 


        int num = ListCtrl->FindItem(&f1, -1); 
        if (num == -1) {
        MessageBox(_T("검색 실패"), MB_OK);
        return;
        }

        ListCtrl->SetItemState(
            num,
            LVIS_FOCUSED | LVIS_SELECTED,
            LVIS_FOCUSED | LVIS_SELECTED
        );
        ListCtrl->EnsureVisible(num, true);
        ListCtrl->SetFocus();
}
```

if i click button focus always on zero row

Comment: I guess that since the virtual list-view control doesn't store the data, it simply won't find anything. You may need to set the `LVIF_DI_SETITEM` flag in your [`LVN_GETDISPINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvn-getdispinfo) for searching to work.

Comment: It's a virtual list control, so you maintain your data, not the control. You must search your data, it's faster to do it yourself (esp if your data are sorted) and not through the control. Finally (as you already do) make sure the item found becomes visible.

Comment: Do you often mix multibyte strings and unicode string?  That usually spells trouble.  I would start by using unicode throughout, as this is the kind of error one would expect when mixing string types.  I would expect a Chinese app to use unicode only.  especially in 2022.